# Is it possible to make my own encryption when sending data through sockets?

Tags: python, encryption

For example in python if I’m sending data through sockets could I make my own encryption algorithm to encrypt that data? Would it be unbreakable since only I know how it works?

Comment: Seriously though, it's a pretty poor idea to try and design your own encryption algorithm.  Have you read about TLS?  Definitely a better way to approach transport security.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark But would it be feasible at all? Or should I just stick with typical methods?

Comment: Nope, definitely not feasible.  With respect, the fact that you're asking this means that you have practically zero experience in cryptography.  With that in mind, do you really think you could design an encryption algorithm that was decent?  Do you know what known-plaintext attacks are?  Frequency analysis?  What about padding oracles and ciphertext authentication?  These are all things you'd have to consider.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark Thanks for the answer! I’m very new to this and just started learning about cryptography and I was curious if it were possible to do.

Comment: Search about existing encryption libraries, and about commonly used encription algorithms and use one of those, don't make your own unless you are studying cryptography (and even in that case I am meaning write it for educational purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Would it be unbreakable? No. This is called security through obscurity. You're relying on the fact that nobody knows how it works. But can you really rely on that?

Someone is going to receive the data, and they'll have to decrypt it. The code must run on their machine for that to happen. If they have the code, they know how it works. Well, at least anyone with a lot of spare time and nothing else to do can easily reverse engineer it, and there goes your obscurity.

Is it feasable to make your own algorithm? Sure. A bit of XOR here, a bit of shuffling there... eventually you'll have an encryption algorithm. It probably wouldn't be a good one but it would do the job, at least until someone tries to break it, then it probably wouldn't last a day.

Does Python care? Do sockets care? No. You can do whatever you want with the data. It's just bits after all, what they mean is up to you.

Are you a cryptographer? No, otherwise you wouldn't be here asking this. So should you do it? No.